# Implementing Semigroup for dependent pair in Idris

Tags: idris

I'm trying to implement the `Semigroup` interface for a simple dependent pair in Idris, but this doesn't compile :

```
Semigroup (n ** Vect n f) where
  (<+>) (_ ** xs) (_ ** ys) = (_ ** xs ++ ys)
```

with the error

```
Type mismatch between
    ty
and
    Nat
```

But this compile :

```
myPair:Type -> Type
myPair f = (n ** Vect n f)

Semigroup (myPair f) where
   (<+>) (_ ** xs) (_ ** ys) = (_ ** xs ++ ys)
```

why ? What is the best way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idris [FAQ](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/faq/faq.html?highlight=lower#why-can-t-i-use-a-function-with-no-arguments-in-a-type):

> If you use a name in a type which begins with a lower case letter, and which is not applied to any arguments, then Idris will treat it as an implicitly bound argument.

One approach to solving the problem would be to get rid of some syntactic sugar and explicitly bind `n` like this:

```
Semigroup (DPair Nat (\n => Vect n f)) where
  (<+>) = (_ ** xs) (_ ** ys) = (_ ** xs ++ ys)
```

Another approach would be to use an upper-case letter for the vector length:

```
Semigroup (N ** Vect N f) where
  (<+>) = (_ ** xs) (_ ** ys) = (_ ** xs ++ ys)
```

Here, `N` does not get bound in the `Semigroup` implementation, and this allows the `DPair` syntactic sugar to kick in and bind `N` just as we did in the first variant.

As for the `myPair` example, it compiles because the example is essentially equivalent to the `DPair` example above. If you just remove the sugar everything becomes clear:

```
myPair:Type -> Type
myPair f = DPair Nat (\n => Vect n f)
```